# Arrays seem to be 0-based instead of 1-based when working with Range and Cells

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-interop

I'm currently evaluating VSTO to replace the VBA we use with Excel 2010, so I'm absolutely new to this Excel interop thing.

While testing, I sometimes encountered issues while using ranges and cells, sometimes the arrays seem to be 1-based and sometimes they seem to be 0-based, and I didn't find any information on that.

Here is a small example :

```
var ws = ((Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]);
var range = ws.Range["B2:D6"];
AddName("testname", range);

range.BorderAround2(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThick);

//Code 1
((Excel.Range)range.Cells[2, 1]).BorderAround2(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThick);
((Excel.Range)range.Cells[4, 1]).BorderAround2(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThick);

//Code 2
range.Range[range.Cells[2, 1], range.Cells[4, 1]].Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Green);

//Code 3
range.Range[range.Cells[1, 0], range.Cells[3, 0]].Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
```

The code creates a named range and adds a thick border around, then adds a double border to the cells that represent the bounds of the range I want.
It sets the background to green for the range that uses the same cells, and in red for the range I want.
Here is the result :
[image]

What I wanted to do is to select the cells of the first column in the range except the first and last (so red is what I want).
But it seems that if I select the cells individually (code 1), it doesn't behave the same as if I create a range from the same cells (code 2).
To get the range I want, I have to shift all indexes by one (0-based) (code 3).

Is there a reason for that, did I miss something ? I don't see anything about that in the MSDN.

Comment: Some times? Seem? ALL THE ARRAYS (or any other kind of collection) IN .NET ARE ALWAYS 0-BASED (sorry for the caps, but yesterday I met various persons who insisted quite a lot in this issue; and it is basic and important enough to not have even the slightest doubt). If you think that, in some contexts, they are 1-based is because you are parsing the information wrongly; but the first columns/rows are always in the 0 position. Note that Interop has nothing to do with VBA; emulates the names, but all the variables are .NET ones and thus 0-based.

Comment: PS: one of the best things of programming is that "seem" can be converted into "know for sure" quite easily in almost any situation. You have just to debug the code under the conditions you have doubts about.

Comment: I've been working with C# for 10 years, so I know how it works, but this is VSTO, so COM interop. If I try to access range.Cells as if it was a 0-based array, I get a COM exception. But not in "code 3". Which is strange. Hence the "seem" : I didn't find the rule...

Comment: Post the exact conditions provoking such a situation and let's see.

Comment: This is what I posted : if I access range.Cells() directly it behaves as if it was 1-based (Cells[1,1] is the first cell of the range). If I access range.Cells() inside a range.Range[cell, cell] array, it behaves as if it was a 0-based array (Cells[0,0] is the first cell of the range). I'm pretty sure I missed something, but I don't know what.

Comment: One second: even by assuming that inside the range the first cell is Cells[1, 1], does Cells[0,0] exists or not? Because if it wouldn't exist, it would be a break of the aforementioned rule of all the .NET collections being 0-based. If not, the contained information is not distributed as intuitively expected within the 0-based array; this is a different story...

Comment: Some interesting comments here : http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Read-the-contents-of-a-worksheet-with-C.aspx re. 1-based & 0-based array & Excel interop.

Comment: @PaulF If this is true, it would mean a break of the aforementioned rule. A conceptual bug.

Comment: @varocarbas Indexes are relative, so in my case, range.Cells[0,0] exists but it is outside of the range (so range.Cells[0, -1] works). This is not really how I'm used to see array work :)

Comment: Ufff... OK. Then, the PaulF answer makes sense (the distribution of the information within the 0-based array under these conditions is bit weird, but well...) and the 0-based absolute rule is maintained. In any case, while reading Excel cells foreach becomes pretty handy and avoids all these problems.

Comment: Then. I guess that PaulF's answer is the right one, isn't it?

Comment: @varocarbas: It does seem to work oddly, but Cells is not actually an array but a Property with two indexes - internally those indexes will be used to access the underlying data. So the 0-based array rule is not being broken. Just looks "wrong" from a C# perspective.

Comment: @PaulF Clarification: the collections in .NET are much more complex than in PHP; there are tons of options. Additionally, I use array almost as a generic term similar to collection (an opossed to List). Cases like Cells are custom array-like implementations (.NET allows you to define many types of variables). Also anything (public) at the class level is called a property (i.e., arrays are also properties depending upon the context). I mean... don't get offended, but why trying to show a knowledge which you don't have. Your (research-based) contribution has been nice, why not remaining there?

Comment: @PaulF You're right, I use the term "array" because the interop has been created to look like one, but it is just relative indexes. What was the most surprising wasn't the 1-based indexing (which is standard VB) but the apparent inconsistent behavior where 1,1 and 0,0 can be the first cell of the range :)

Comment: @JulienN Cells is a standard .NET collection all the .NET collections share the same basic "characteristics" (one of them being 0-based), by inheriting from the corresponding interface(s). Calling cells an array (a 2-D array) is fine (as explained above, understood as a .NET collection different than a List). Cells inherits from the same than arrays/lists that's why not being non-zero-based would be a problem (how could it be possible!? -> bug).

Comment: @JulienN: I agree that the behaviour is very inconsistent - and not helped by the poor MS documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Remarks here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.range.aspx. With the Range property the cells are relative to the defined range, hence the shift by 1.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't see this remark. But I'm not sure it explains what I have, as the range.Cells[] is also relative to the range (I'm using the same range for all code examples), it doesn't explain why it doesn't behave the same. The link in your comment is interesting though.

Comment: @JulienN your problem is explained perfectly. It refers to range.Range (= Excel range variable). That is: you define a range variable (like "A2:C10") and while looping through the cells within this variable. It is a weird (and not too consistent) definition, but explains your problem.

Comment: @JulienN : As there is no such comment in the Cells property page, I am guessing those are working as expected with offsets relative to the whole worksheet.